# How to detect Display zoom programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I can't find how can I detect in code when the display zoom is changed from the device Settings:

[image]

Is there any way to detect the Display Zoom for all iPhone devices, which all are devices supporting this feature?

Comment: @vrwim: This provides a solution for iPhone 6 and iPhone Plus in a hardcode manner. But is there any solution for this irrespective of the device type? Means validation should support all devices from iPhone 6 to iPhone 11 pro max

Comment: @vrwim Can it be correct? 
let mainScreen = UIScreen.main
        
        if mainScreen.scale == mainScreen.nativeScale {
            print("Standard mode")
        } else {
            print("Zoomed mode")
        }